# Mantener un usuario logueado en las vistas

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy tratando de realizar que cuando registre un usuario, me aparezca su nombre de usuario en la cabecera de la página. Todo esto en ASP.NET. Tengo hecho la validación y compruebo que realmente el usuario existe, pero ahora quiero que me muestre su nombre en la cabecera.

El problema surge que por ejemplo la parte de la cabecera lo tengo todo en la pagina maestra `_Layout.cshtml` entonces no se como podría pasar ese dato hasta esa vista. Mi `_Layout` lo tengo así:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="header-container">
        <div class="row" id="header">
            <div class="col-12 navbar-personalize" id="menu">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-lg'>
                        <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">NaturaLife</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-around ctmenu" id="navbarNav">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav menu">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Index">Inicio</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Productos">Productos</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Recetas</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/AboutUs">¿Quienes Somos?</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactanos</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="navbar-nav menu">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/IngresoRegistro"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Productos"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                </li>
                                @{

                                }
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">NombreUser</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12" id="content-desc">
                <div class="fondo"></div>
                <div class="novedades">
                    <h1>Hola, <span class="ramdom"></span><span class="cursor">|</span></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

En la parte donde tengo `NombreUser` es donde quiero pasar el dato y que muestre el nombre. Esta cabecera es común para todas mis páginas obviamente, por eso creí que debe ir en `_Layout.html`.

Si alguien me pudiese orientar como hacerlo, he leido con los `partialView` pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: Dependiendo del tipo de autenticación que utilices podrías usar directamente la propiedad User: `User?.Identity.GetUserName()`

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza una variable de sesión:

```
Session["name"] = name;
```

y para leerlo en la misma clase sería:

```
name = (string)(Session["name"]);
```

mientras que en una clase externa sería:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
name = (string)(context.Session["name"]);
```

Puedes encontrar información mas detallada en [la documentación de Session](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-and-access-447ada98)